# get s3 object expiration in golang

Tags: go, amazon-s3

There seems to be a way to set expiration days in an upload by attaching a Metadata with an "expdays" key to the PutObjectInput but there doesn't appear to be any way to then get this metadata from an object in like a "ListObjects" call. ListObjectOutput returns "Contents" which is a list of s3.Objects but that object doesn't have a metadata field and I don't see any other way to get it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ListObjects` calls return a `[]Object` for the actual object list in the result, and `Object` does not include the expiration. However, `GetObject` returns [`GetObjectOutput`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#GetObjectOutput) which does have an `Expiration` field. So you could iterate your returned `Object`s and get the expiration for each, though this could be time-consuming if there are many of them.

Comment: You'll have to [take it up with the AWS SDK for Go team](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues).

Comment: There's no reason to take it up with the SDK team.  The underlying S3 APIs for ListObjects do not return user metadata or tags.  Fetching this *requires* individual `HEAD` requests for each object. (...which is why I use S3 event notifications, Lambda, and RDS/MariaDB to build indexes of my object metadata, captured when the objects are uploaded...)

Comment: Well then, with the API team. Either way, not something that can be solved on SO.